# Accordion of ng-bootstrap not occupying full width of a component in an Angular 11 app

Tags: css, angular, accordion, ng-bootstrap

I am using Accordion component of ng-bootstrap in one of the components of my Angular 11 app. The accordion occupies only the width of content inside it as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

I want the accordion to occupy full available width of screen as shown below

[image]

The code in the section.component.html file is

```
<ngb-accordion [closeOthers]="true" activeIds="static-1">
   <ngb-panel id="static-1" title="Section1">
     <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
       abc
     </ng-template>
   </ngb-panel>
   <ngb-panel id="static-2" title="Section2">
     <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
       def
     </ng-template>
   </ngb-panel>
   <ngb-panel id="static-3" title="Section3" >
     <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
       ghi
     </ng-template>
   </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

I imported both NgbAccordionModule and NgbModule in the section.module.ts file as shown below

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { SectionRoutingModule } from './section-routing.module';
import { SectionComponent } from './section.component';
import { NgbAccordionModule, NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [SectionComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SectionRoutingModule,
    NgbAccordionModule,
    NgbModule
 ]
})
export class SectionModule { }
```

I don't know what is causing this issue. Please help me out with this

Comment: Did u try giving cardClass="w-100" to ngb-panel?

Comment: By default it should take the full width of parent element. Please re-check the full component html. Try using chrome dev tools to see where the full width of body is being taken away by which element or what css

Comment: I added cardClass="w-100" to ngb-panel but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Post your code on stackblitz or codepen